# Filtering out UUId number from a string

Tags: java, regex, uuid

I want to filter out into a new string only the strings that has UUID number 
example:

```
02bfa116-c834-4896-b825-e8f1299319f9,8.1.0,2888F244914F75CD68DC70A11B71BF0420F,panos
```

Expected: getting a new string that will contain this value '02bfa116-c834-4896-b825-e8f1299319f9'

what I've tried so far:

```
final String regex = "[a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8}";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arr[i]);
            contentCSVStr[i] = matcher.group();
        }
```

where each string inside the array could be in the format I gave in the example above.

when I run this code I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Is UUID a standard format ? I know it's hex parts separated by dash, but are the parts any standard size and amount ?

Comment: Because your regex matches 'bfa116-c834-4896-b825-e8f1`299319f9-c834-4896-b825-e8f1299319f9`,8.1.0,2888F244914F75CD68DC70A11B71BF0420F,panos' You may want to think about fixing that so it doesn't happen.

Comment: It is a good usage question +1.

Comment: Please do not reopen the question. It is a very common issue that has been [broadly covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/12911504?lq=1) at SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forgetting the call to [`Matcher.find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

Change your code to this:

```
final String regex = "[a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8}";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(args[i]);
    matcher.find(); // <- This line needed to be added
    contentCSVStr[i] = matcher.group();
}
```

And it will correctly extract the UUID.

`group` returns the results of the previous match, but until you call `find` no match has happened yet, so it has no results to return.

Comment: Good answer +1. Unfortunately, nobody with the same problem will ever get to see it as the Duplicate guy marked your answer as unreadable. He seems to think every question is a duplicate.

Comment: @sln - agree what can I do lol